# Is it posible to install Hortonworks Cluster on Docker on one single Linux machine

Tags: ambari, hdp

We want to build test Hadoop cluster on one Linux machine based on docker container/s

Dose hortonworks ( cloudera ) support this ? ,

For example HDP version - 2.6.5

For example we need the following services

```
HDFS ( include at least 3 data-nodes ,  )
YARN
MAPreduce2
HIVE
Zookeeper
Ambari metrics
KAFKA
SPARK2
```

and all these services should be on one Linux machine

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jessica it is not possible to do a 3 node (hdfs) instance with a single node machine.  Other than that, a single node cluster can run all of the services you have listed and is suitable for learning, training, and demos or proof of concepts.

Comment: can you show me please the link to installed the docer machine with all services node from cloudera